# Redirecting to Home Page if session not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating a form where data is coming from previous form and i'm storing that data in session. If user directly visits second page than I want the user to redirect to first page, but I can't find any way to do it. Is it possible?

```
my code(second page)

def get(self, request):
    a = request.session['a']
```

since a is not set if user directly visits this page I want him to redirect to first page if session not found.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the user if the key is missing in the session:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def get(self, request):
    if 'a' not in request.session:
        return redirect("name_of_first_view")
    # ...
```